# I can't seem to get entity association to work when column type is guid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to do something that should be very simple create a association between to tables but the columns in question are guids and I appear to be having difficulty

[image]

My settings for the association are:

[image]

SQL Server fk settings:

[image]

But when I build I get the following error; is there any special I need to do or am I doing something wrong when constructing the association?

> Severity Code   Description   Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - tblPortalUserRequestedDoctblPortalUserRequestDocumentType.    portalef    C:\Projects\dashboard\portalef\portalModel.edmx 447

And finally, my two entities look like this:

[image]

If someone could point me into the right direction of what I am doing wrong I would be most grateful

Then when I try the mapping I get the following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 622, 649:Two entities with possibly different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments map both ends of the AssociationSet to the corresponding columns.  portalef    C:\Projects\dashboard\portalef\portalModel.edmx 623

[image]

Comment: You should swap "one" and "many" parts of your association.

Comment: @IvanStoev can you provide an example so i can give you rep mate

Comment: No worry mate, glad if helped solving the issue. Feel free to post a self answer if you wish.

Comment: @IvanStoev i kinda need the guidance in graphical form as didnt really understand what you ment sorry

Answer (score 0):

Add new property to tblPortalUserRequestDocumentType entity named tblPortalUserRequestedDocId

Comment: your answer has no relvanace without any example to the prelude one you have not even read the title of the entity correctly is no such one called tblPortalUserRequestedDocId